# scrape-it node modules won't hit the URL when called in a loop for multiple URLs, Yes! I' using async-await

Tags: node.js, web-scraping

I'm using Node.js and trying to scrape some data using scrape-it node module.
I've following code, I'm trying to loop through an array of URLs and want to scrape some data from them. However, this code won't even hit the URLs at first place when in loop. Without loop, with a single URL it works well.

```
const promises = URLs.map(async url => {
    const { data } = await scrapeIt(URLs, {
      // Fetch the List of Items
      items: {
        listItem: 'table.data.frontPageWidget > tbody > tr',
        data: {
          title: {
            selector: '.cellMainLink'
          },
          details: {
            selector: '.cellMainLink',
            attr: 'href'
          },
          size: {
            selector: 'td:nth-of-type(2)'
          }
        }
      } 
    });
    return data;
  });
```

I tried with promise.all also, to make sure tasks are finished first. My expectation is that I should be able to hit multiple URLs while looping an array of them and scrape the data successfully.